# Trying to switching text between 2 files

Tags: python, file-io

```
from sys import argv

script, f1, f2 = argv

print """This program is going to switch the 
content of the two files you just selected."""

first_file = open(f1, 'r+')
first_content = first_file.read()


second_file = open(f2, 'r+')
second_content = second_file.read()


final_first = first_file.write(second_content)
final_second = second_file.write(first_content)
```

---

IOError: [Errno 0] Error

---

I'm trying to switch the content between two text files simultaneously. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reached the EOF (end of the file).

Try call `first_file.seek(0,0)` and `second_file.seek(0, 0)` before writing

There are easier ways to swap file content e.g. by renaming the files

Comment: Don't have 15 reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

You should try a simple rename operation

```
import os

f3 = 'temp.file'
os.rename(f1, f3)
os.rename(f2, f1)
os.rename(f3, f2)
```